# Cartpole-v0 loss increasing using DQN

Tags: python, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

Hi I'm trying to train a DQN to solve gym's Cartpole problem. 
For some reason the [Loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHxpR.png) looks like this (orange line). Can y'all take a look at my code and help with this? I've played around with the hyperparameters a decent bit so I don't think they're the issue here.

```py
class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 16)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(32, 32)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(32, output_dim)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear3(x))
        return self.linear4(x)


final_epsilon = 0.05
initial_epsilon = 1
epsilon_decay = 5000
global steps_done
steps_done = 0


def select_action(state):
    global steps_done
    sample = random.random()
    eps_threshold = final_epsilon + (initial_epsilon - final_epsilon) * \
                    math.exp(-1. * steps_done / epsilon_decay)
    if sample > eps_threshold:
        with torch.no_grad():
            state = torch.Tensor(state)
            steps_done += 1
            q_calc = model(state)
            node_activated = int(torch.argmax(q_calc))
            return node_activated
    else:
        node_activated = random.randint(0,1)
        steps_done += 1
        return node_activated


class ReplayMemory(object): # Stores [state, reward, action, next_state, done]

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = [[],[],[],[],[]]

    def push(self, data):
        """Saves a transition."""
        for idx, point in enumerate(data):
            #print("Col {} appended {}".format(idx, point))
            self.memory[idx].append(point)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        rows = random.sample(range(0, len(self.memory[0])), batch_size)
        experiences = [[],[],[],[],[]]
        for row in rows:
            for col in range(5):
                experiences[col].append(self.memory[col][row])
        return experiences

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory[0])


input_dim, output_dim = 4, 2
model = DQN(input_dim, output_dim)
target_net = DQN(input_dim, output_dim)
target_net.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())
target_net.eval()
tau = 2
discount = 0.99

learning_rate = 1e-4
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

memory = ReplayMemory(65536)
BATCH_SIZE = 128


def optimize_model():
    if len(memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
        return 0
    experiences = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
    state_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[0])
    action_batch = torch.LongTensor(experiences[1]).unsqueeze(1)
    reward_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[2])
    next_state_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[3])
    done_batch = experiences[4]

    pred_q = model(state_batch).gather(1, action_batch)

    next_state_q_vals = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE)

    for idx, next_state in enumerate(next_state_batch):
        if done_batch[idx] == True:
            next_state_q_vals[idx] = -1
        else:
            # .max in pytorch returns (values, idx), we only want vals
            next_state_q_vals[idx] = (target_net(next_state_batch[idx]).max(0)[0]).detach()


    better_pred = (reward_batch + next_state_q_vals).unsqueeze(1)

    loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(pred_q, better_pred)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.grad.data.clamp_(-1, 1)
    optimizer.step()
    return loss


points = []
losspoints = []

#save_state = torch.load("models/DQN_target_11.pth")
#model.load_state_dict(save_state['state_dict'])
#optimizer.load_state_dict(save_state['optimizer'])



env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
for i_episode in range(5000):
    observation = env.reset()
    episode_loss = 0
    if episode % tau == 0:
        target_net.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())
    for t in range(1000):
        #env.render()
        state = observation
        action = select_action(observation)
        observation, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

        if done:
            next_state = [0,0,0,0]
        else:
            next_state = observation

        memory.push([state, action, reward, next_state, done])
        episode_loss = episode_loss + float(optimize_model(i_episode))
        if done:
            points.append((i_episode, t+1))
            print("Episode {} finished after {} timesteps".format(i_episode, t+1))
            print("Avg Loss: ", episode_loss / (t+1))
            losspoints.append((i_episode, episode_loss / (t+1)))
            if (i_episode % 100 == 0):
                eps = final_epsilon + (initial_epsilon - final_epsilon) * \
                    math.exp(-1. * steps_done / epsilon_decay)
                print(eps)
            if ((i_episode+1) % 5001 == 0):
                save = {'state_dict': model.state_dict(), 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
                torch.save(save, "models/DQN_target_" + str(i_episode // 5000) + ".pth")
            break
env.close()




x = [coord[0] * 100 for coord in points]
y = [coord[1] for coord in points]

x2 = [coord[0] * 100 for coord in losspoints]
y2 = [coord[1] for coord in losspoints]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

I basically followed the tutorial pytorch has, except using the state returned by the env rather than the pixels. I also changed the replay memory because I was having issues there. Other than that, I left everything else pretty much the same.

Edit:

I tried overfitting on a small batch and the Loss looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwjrU.png) without updating the target net and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOOPM.png) when updating it

Edit 2:

This is definitely an issue with the target net, I tried removing it and loss seemed to not increase exponentially

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your `tau` value is too small, small target network update cause DQN traning unstable. You can try to use 1000 (OpenAI Baseline's DQN example) or 10000 (Deepmind's Nature paper).

In Deepmind's 2015 Nature paper, it states that:

> The second modification to online Q-learning aimed at further improving the stability of our method with neural networks is to use a separate network for generating the traget yj in the Q-learning update. More precisely, every C updates we clone the network Q to obtain a target network Q' and use Q' for generating the Q-learning targets y<sub>j</sub> for the following C updates to Q. 
>   This modification makes the algorithm more stable compared to standard online Q-learning, where an update that increases Q(s<sub>t</sub>,a<sub>t</sub>) often also increases Q(s<sub>t+1</sub>, a) for all a and hence also increases the target y<sub>j</sub>, possibly leading to oscillations or divergence of the policy. Generating the targets using the older set of parameters adds a delay between the time an update to Q is made and the time the update affects the targets y<sub>j</sub>, making divergence or oscillations much more unlikely.

[Human-level control through deep reinforcement
learning, Mnih et al., 2015](https://web.stanford.edu/class/psych209/Readings/MnihEtAlHassibis15NatureControlDeepRL.pdf)

I've run your code with settings of `tau=2`, `tau=10`, `tau=100`, `tau=1000` and `tau=10000`. The update frequency of `tau=100` solves the problem (reach maximum steps of 200).

`tau=2`

[image]

`tau=10`
[image]

`tau=100`
[image]

`tau=1000`
[image]

`tau=10000`
[image]

Below is the modified version of your code.

```py
import random
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import gym

class DQN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        super(DQN, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 16)
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(16, 32)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(32, 32)
        self.linear4 = nn.Linear(32, output_dim)


    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.linear3(x))
        return self.linear4(x)


final_epsilon = 0.05
initial_epsilon = 1
epsilon_decay = 5000
global steps_done
steps_done = 0


def select_action(state):
    global steps_done
    sample = random.random()
    eps_threshold = final_epsilon + (initial_epsilon - final_epsilon) * \
                    math.exp(-1. * steps_done / epsilon_decay)
    if sample > eps_threshold:
        with torch.no_grad():
            state = torch.Tensor(state)
            steps_done += 1
            q_calc = model(state)
            node_activated = int(torch.argmax(q_calc))
            return node_activated
    else:
        node_activated = random.randint(0,1)
        steps_done += 1
        return node_activated


class ReplayMemory(object): # Stores [state, reward, action, next_state, done]

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity
        self.memory = [[],[],[],[],[]]

    def push(self, data):
        """Saves a transition."""
        for idx, point in enumerate(data):
            #print("Col {} appended {}".format(idx, point))
            self.memory[idx].append(point)

    def sample(self, batch_size):
        rows = random.sample(range(0, len(self.memory[0])), batch_size)
        experiences = [[],[],[],[],[]]
        for row in rows:
            for col in range(5):
                experiences[col].append(self.memory[col][row])
        return experiences

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.memory[0])


input_dim, output_dim = 4, 2
model = DQN(input_dim, output_dim)
target_net = DQN(input_dim, output_dim)
target_net.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())
target_net.eval()
tau = 100
discount = 0.99

learning_rate = 1e-4
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

memory = ReplayMemory(65536)
BATCH_SIZE = 128


def optimize_model():
    if len(memory) < BATCH_SIZE:
        return 0
    experiences = memory.sample(BATCH_SIZE)
    state_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[0])
    action_batch = torch.LongTensor(experiences[1]).unsqueeze(1)
    reward_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[2])
    next_state_batch = torch.Tensor(experiences[3])
    done_batch = experiences[4]

    pred_q = model(state_batch).gather(1, action_batch)

    next_state_q_vals = torch.zeros(BATCH_SIZE)

    for idx, next_state in enumerate(next_state_batch):
        if done_batch[idx] == True:
            next_state_q_vals[idx] = -1
        else:
            # .max in pytorch returns (values, idx), we only want vals
            next_state_q_vals[idx] = (target_net(next_state_batch[idx]).max(0)[0]).detach()


    better_pred = (reward_batch + next_state_q_vals).unsqueeze(1)

    loss = F.smooth_l1_loss(pred_q, better_pred)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.grad.data.clamp_(-1, 1)
    optimizer.step()
    return loss


points = []
losspoints = []

#save_state = torch.load("models/DQN_target_11.pth")
#model.load_state_dict(save_state['state_dict'])
#optimizer.load_state_dict(save_state['optimizer'])



env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
for i_episode in range(5000):
    observation = env.reset()
    episode_loss = 0
    if i_episode % tau == 0:
        target_net.load_state_dict(model.state_dict())
    for t in range(1000):
        #env.render()
        state = observation
        action = select_action(observation)
        observation, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

        if done:
            next_state = [0,0,0,0]
        else:
            next_state = observation

        memory.push([state, action, reward, next_state, done])
        episode_loss = episode_loss + float(optimize_model())
        if done:
            points.append((i_episode, t+1))
            print("Episode {} finished after {} timesteps".format(i_episode, t+1))
            print("Avg Loss: ", episode_loss / (t+1))
            losspoints.append((i_episode, episode_loss / (t+1)))
            if (i_episode % 100 == 0):
                eps = final_epsilon + (initial_epsilon - final_epsilon) * \
                    math.exp(-1. * steps_done / epsilon_decay)
                print(eps)
            if ((i_episode+1) % 5001 == 0):
                save = {'state_dict': model.state_dict(), 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
                torch.save(save, "models/DQN_target_" + str(i_episode // 5000) + ".pth")
            break
env.close()




x = [coord[0] * 100 for coord in points]
y = [coord[1] for coord in points]

x2 = [coord[0] * 100 for coord in losspoints]
y2 = [coord[1] for coord in losspoints]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x2, y2)
plt.show()
```

Here's the result of your plotting code.

`tau=100`
[image]

`tau=10000`
[image: Blue is the average period and orange is the loss]

Comment: Wow, really in depth answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Please, labels the axes

Comment: Sorry, @dc914337, the plot was too old; either I can't find the original script, and worst of all, I'm awful at using plotting. The plots were used to describe the small tau number makes model prediction diverges meanwhile causing the agent to be unable to learn from the reward. The x-axis is the cycle number, and the y-axis is the RMSD of the model prediction and actual reward.